# Error 500 during Sonar runner execution on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am getting the below error when running sonarqube standalone analysis on Jenkins. The sonarqube scanner is able to identify the files to be analyzed and is able to analyze them fine, but the issue is when it is trying to publish the project to dashboard.

When I open the URL http://vv123456:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=pkey&projectName=pname in browser, it says *"{"errors":[{"msg":"HTTP method POST is required"}]}"*, which means the sonarqube webservice is fine.

**Error on Jenkins build:**

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on [http://vv123456:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=pkey&projectName=pname][1]
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:34)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.failIfUnauthorized(BatchWsClient.java:99)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.call(BatchWsClient.java:69)
    at org.sonar.batch.report.ReportPublisher.upload(ReportPublisher.java:172)
    at org.sonar.batch.report.ReportPublisher.execute(ReportPublisher.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PublishPhaseExecutor.publishReportJob(PublishPhaseExecutor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PublishPhaseExecutor.executeOnRoot(PublishPhaseExecutor.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:86)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:79)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: 500 means internal server error. Are u sure about the way you used to conform sonar is working property? Also what are version of tools?

Comment: @Shiva - Yes, I can see on Jenkins build that Sonar analysis is successful, I see the log as below:
14:53:46.992 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
14:53:46.993 INFO  - SCM provider for this project is: svn
14:53:47.009 INFO  - 4 files to be analyzed
14:53:50.574 INFO  - 4/4 files analyzed
14:53:50.575 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=3583ms
14:53:50.576 INFO  - Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor

The version I am using are - Jenkins 1.580.1, SonarQube 2.2.1

Comment: Anything interesting in `$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs/web.log`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the SonarQube logs on the server where web-service is hosted (vv123456 in my case), there was an error logged as:

```
No such file or directory - C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/AppData/Local/Temp
```

So, I added the path to the temp location in wrapper.conf as:

```
set.TMPDIR=/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.6/temp
```

This resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this helped me!

Answer (score 6):

I'm experiencing this problem too. Looking in the logs at `/opt/sonar/logs/sonar.log` I can see the following error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (9122692 > 4194304). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
```

Used advice from here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/packet-too-large.html

and here

[PacketTooBigException when running a sonar analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592351/packettoobigexception-when-running-a-sonar-analysis)

and here

http://codefabulae.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/sonar-analysis-and-mysql-max-packet.html

The final solution was to write this in to my mysql config `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=32M
```

restart mysqld

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```

and check it via

```
mysql <insert user credentials here>
mysql> show variables like "max_allowed%";
```

and then reboot sonar

```
sudo service sonar restart
```

Then my build stopped having the 500 error as mentioned.

This is how to fix the issue PacketTooBig, which is a likely root cause.

Comment: That was my problem as well, but it took me some time to find the relevant log file. In my case it was /etc/sonarqube/logs/web.log (used `find / -type f -name web.log` to find it after I saw https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/c_DcwoN4qlg)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution : 
User have to increase the max_allowed_packet size at the Mysql My.config file as well as Mysql connection string at the sonar.config.

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&max_allowed_packet=512M
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this procedure, it worked for me:

1. Stop the Sonar Server
2. Go to Sonarqube Location and delete the contents in **temp** folder
3. Start the Sonar Server and run again.