# Error Sonarqube IllegalStateException: Fail to request http://192.xx.yy.zz:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

When I activate the integration between Jenkins and Sonarqube, with a project having already put data on the sonar website, I get the error during the Sonarqube scanner execution.

This error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Fail to request http://192.168.163.128:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=itoo-exam-api&projectName=itoo-exam-api
```

How would you troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the full debug log, as [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/Kb6P40f-lno):

> I enabled `-X` at the `sonar_run.bat` then found out that it required the following path

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp
```

> to exists, my case is that I am without the `Temp` folder, so the upload failed with the above error.

(Or add a [`TEMPDIR` variable as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38012795/6309))

More generally, do check the sonarqube logs.

Comment: thank you Vonc，the day after that day,the problem is not re-appear,I guss ,maybe the network or other things to lead  this problem.thanks again